# Hashing string in cpp own version

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

I have to implement a string hashing function in c++
In case of int it's not so hard, but how to do it in case of string without external libraries?

Comment: Use `std::hash` string specialization.

Comment: I have to write my own hashing function without using built-in methods

Comment: Every character can be represented as an int (in fact, every data type is some kind of int at the end). So string is just a sequence of ints (but treated as chars). That should be enough to figure out the answer yourself.

Comment: see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/hash for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple hash function that I would suggest for strings is by considering ASCII value of each character. So, follow these steps to get the hash value.

1. Compute the sum of all the ASCII value corresponding to the characters of your string.
2. hash_value = sum%N

where N = size of the hash table

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of hash algorithms. If you want a simple, not-too-high quality one, use djb2 (from [here](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html)):

```
unsigned long
hash(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash;
}
```

If you want a better one, check out [smhasher](https://github.com/rurban/smhasher) for a lot of algorithms.